# Error in mode == "ALL" : comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Tags: r

when I run

```
if(mode=="ALL") {}
```

it returns

> Error in mode == "ALL" :    comparison (1) is possible only for atomic
> and list types

I try to start with new workspace, and detach some package, but did not work
what can I do?

Comment: What is `mode`?

Answer (score 0):

`mode` is a function:

```r
# This doesn't work...
mode == "all"
#> Error in mode == "all": comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

# ...because mode is a function
is.function(mode)
#> [1] TRUE


# You need to save something to mode - and thus overwriting the function -
# before comparing it:

mode <- "all"
mode == "all"
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Save something else as `mode` or change the name of your variable.